# Allow users to create other users in Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Sort of a Rails beginner here.. My application uses Devise for authentication. What I need it to do is allow users, once signed in, to create other users that belong to the same organization as him.

Problem is I can't just use the default Devise new registration form since it doesn't allow me to access it when I'm signed in (I'm thinking I can override this by generating my own User controller?).

Plus, the user table has an organization_id (automatically created on signup) and I need the form to pass the current_user.organization_id for organization_id, and the default form won't let me do that.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to create a custom form that'll have all the required user fields and pass the form values to one of your controllers which will take the params something like this:

```
def create
    User.create!({:email => params[:email], :roles => ["role/organization here"], :password => params[:password], :password_confirmation => params[:password_confirmation] })
end
```

In addition to this you should secure this action with one of the `before_filter` which will check if the user is currently logged in and able to create new users?

Hope that helps.

Comment: I eventually went with Authlogic because Devise was giving me way too much problems at the controller side of things. I also did things a whole different way. But I still took your suggestion of creating another form and storing it in a partial. Thanks :)